# Did Voldemort kill half-bloods too during the FWW?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, death-eaters

Or was it only Muggles and Muggle-borns? I'm writing a story and I need a little bit of help.

Answer (score 13):

Did he kill some Half-bloods? I assume some. Did he kill them as a targeted campaign against Half-bloods? There's no canonical answer, but almost certainly not.

The Death Eaters clearly consider Pure-bloods superior to Half-bloods (consider all the bile Harry gets for his "Muggle" mother). But during the Second Wizarding War, they weren't actively discriminated against to the extent that Muggle-borns were. Half-bloods, for example, were allowed to attend Hogwarts while Muggle-borns were not, and were not required to register with the Ministry.

Voldemort says before and during the Battle of Hogwarts that he doesn't want to spill "magical blood," and his actions largely demonstrate that (even Muggle-borns are usually only stripped of their wands or sent to Azkaban). The amount of Wizards who are actually pure-blooded is tiny. I don't see Voldemort willingly committing to the destruction of such a huge number of wizards... including himself.

Answer (score 0):

I thought so, but the fact that his father was a mugglet makes me think that he did not kill half-bloods when it was not necessary. Although he hate his Muggle father, he had conscience that he was half-blood, so there would he think that pure bloods were superior to half bloods, as this would mean that it can not be superior to other wizards, even if descendant Slytherin, for the sole reason of having a Muggle father.

Answer (score 0):

## The Dark Lord didn’t target half-bloods.

Though it’s likely he killed some half-bloods for reasons other than their blood status, the Dark Lord only targeted Mudbloods for their blood status, never half-bloods. Under his rule, anyone who couldn’t prove they had at least one close wizarding relative was punished, but anyone who could prove a wizard relative wasn’t.

> “Nevertheless, unless you can prove that you have at least one close wizarding relative, you are now deemed to have obtained your magical power illegally and must suffer the punishment.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 11 (The Bribe)*</sup></sub>

These conditions would of course mean all half-bloods would be safe, as all half-bloods have at least one parent who’s a wizard. Further proof is that in the hearings determining blood status, one wizard claimed he was a half-blood as an attempt to get himself freed. If half-bloods were also targeted under the Dark Lord’s rule, this would be a useless claim.

> ‘No, no, I’m half-blood, I’m half-blood, I tell you! My father was a wizard, he was, look him up, Arkie Alderton, he’s a well-known broomstick designer, look him up, I tell you – get your hands off me, get your hands off –” <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 13 (The Muggle-born Registration Commission)*</sup></sub>

The Ministry under the Dark Lord’s control gave rewards to anyone who captured and turned in Mudbloods and blood traitors, but no rewards were mentioned as being given for bringing in half-bloods.

> “Snatchers,’ said Ron. ‘They’re everywhere, gangs trying to earn gold by rounding up Muggle-borns and blood traitors, there’s a reward from the Ministry for everyone captured. I was on my own and I look like I might be school age, they got really excited, thought I was a Muggle-born in hiding. I had to talk fast to get out of being dragged to the Ministry.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 19 (The Silver Doe)*</sup></sub>

The Dark Lord was certainly willing to kill specific half-bloods if they were in his way, like Harry Potter - he was willing to kill anyone of any blood status if they were sufficiently in his way. However, it’s clear that half-bloods weren’t actively tracked down by his Ministry to be removed from wizarding society by any means. In the official Ministry position, wizards with no proven wizarding ancestry were said to have stolen their magic, which is why they should be put on trial and arrested.

> “Recent research undertaken by the Department of Mysteries reveals that magic can only be passed from person to person when wizards reproduce. Where no proven wizarding ancestry exists, therefore, the so-called Muggle-born is likely to have obtained magical power by theft or force.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 11 (The Bribe)*</sup></sub>

Half-bloods do have wizarding ancestry, though it’s not *pure* wizarding ancestry. So, this wouldn’t be used as a reason to arrest half-bloods.

Comment: Wait what's the difference between 'Mudbloods' and 'Half-bloods'? I always thought 'Mudblood' was just a really rude way of saying 'Half-bloods'.

Comment: @JamesDouglas Mudbloods are wizards born to two Muggle parents, also called Muggle-borns. Half-bloods are wizards with at least one wizard parent. Half-bloods also may have two wizard parents but have Muggle ancestry - they’re not pure-bloods, so they’re half-bloods instead.

Comment: Not sure how accurate [harrypotter.wikia.com](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Mudblood) is, but it says that _"Mudblood is a highly derogatory term for a Muggle-born or half-blood wizard or witch;"_

Comment: @JamesDouglas It’s only Muggle-borns. *“Mudblood’s a really foul name for someone who was Muggle-born – you know, non-magic parents.”- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 7 (Mudbloods and Murmurs)*